# Given a list of user ids, how can I get these users profiles?

Tags: apex, profile, user

All I've been able to find is the method `UserInfo.getProfileId()` which will only get the logged in user's profile ID. I need to get the profile of a list of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the list and add the profile Ids to a set like this:

```
public static Set<Id> getProfilesFromUser(List<User> userList>){
   Set<Id> setProfileIds= new Set<Id>();
   for(User u : userList){
       setProfileIds.add(u.ProfileId);
   }
   return setProfileIds;
}
```

you should now have a set of all profile Ids for all the users in the initial list

Comment: Ah didn't see ProfileId as an option, thanks!